Is there a way to get information on a Notion teamspace through the api?
I am creating a Notion integration and I need information about the teamspaces (id, name, etc.), and also which teamspace each page/database belongs to. Is there a way to get this data from the api?
I didn't find any endpoint which refers to teamspaces. The parent of the first pages/databases in the hierarchy is the workspace.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
